# Bottom-Up Evaluation of Inherited Attributes

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers, attribute-grammars

I came across $2$ translation schemes of Syntax Directed Translation (SDT) in compilers which are as follows :

- Using a top-down translation scheme, we can implement any
  $L$-attributed definition based on a $LL(1)$ grammar.
- Using a bottom-up translation scheme, we can also implement any
  $L$-attributed definition based on a $LL(1)$ grammar (each $LL(1)$ grammar
  is also an $LR(1)$ grammar).

What these $2$ Definitions actually mean ? I am not getting ..

---

I am well aware of $L$-attributed definition and $S$-attributed definition of SDT and top down parsing and bottom up parsing but It is just that I am unable to recollect this information and phrase it according to the definitions given above.

---

It would be good, if I can get one example of both definitions so, that I can phrase it meaningfully of what is said .

Answer (score 3):

- Using a top-down translation scheme, we can implement any $LL$-attributed definition based on $LL(1)$ grammar.
- Using a bottom-up translation scheme, we can **also** implement any $LL$-attributed definition based on $LL(1)$ grammar (**each** $LL(1)$ grammar is also an $LR(1)$ grammar).  Using bottom-up translation scheme, we implement $LR$ grammar actually but since $LL(1) \subset LR(1)$ we can safely implement $LL(1)$ grammar as well. 
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

[LL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar) Means Left read and Left derived and [LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) is Left read and Right derived the left and right part generally makes the difference between how the parser is written and if it top down or bottom up parsing.

The [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) should be your go-to reference for anything related to parsers and parsing techniques.